# How to get Symbolic crash repost ios xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I am going to check my device crash log of iPhone 5s. But the crash logs are written in unsymbolic format, which is not able to understand.

i have already done the symbolic method using terminal as below[image]

[image]

if you have any info related to this issue then please share with me..... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
DEVELOPER_DIR=`xcode-select -print-path` ./symbolicatecrash -v igolive.crash igoliverel.app.dSYM